# Is there a way to page break `empheq`?

Tags: page-breaking, empheq

I have a very long series of equations that I want to align and emphasize by boxing them. I've used `empheq` with success before, but never ran into the problem of having my equations over flowing to another page. Is there a way to have the box terminate at the bottom of the page and continue on the other page while retaining the equation alignment?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible for individual boxes. What you can do is to put the whole series of equations in a `framed` environment, which will break across pages.

Comment: It is stated in the `empheq` manual that the `empheq` blocks cannot be broken.

Comment: @daleif - I think you should convert your comment to an answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

One of the side-effects of using `empheq` us that the math construction cannot be broken across pages and `\intertext` is not supported.

The reason is that `empheq` is actually using `aligned` and friends internally, and these have this limitation. `Empheq` adds custom eq numbering to these inner constructions.

Comment: Is there a package that would permit this?

Comment: @nonameswereavailable not that I know of, unless tcolorbox has some tricks up its sleeve