# Page breaking boxed equations into two pages

Tags: page-breaking, empheq

I have a very long series of equations that I want to align and emphasize by boxing them. The problem is that so many long equations often need to be broken into two pages, otherwise I get lots of blank vertical space in the document. However the `empheq` environment does not allow to break the box into two pages, as stated in this post [Is there a way to page break `empheq`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326068/is-there-a-way-to-page-break-empheq) and in the documentation https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/empheq.pdf

Anyway, I NEED to break those equations even if that implies abandoning `empheq` and switching to other package.

Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,92,148}
\colorlet{lightblue}{myblue!10}       

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newcommand*\importantequation[1]{\fboxrule=1pt\fboxsep=10pt\fcolorbox{myblue}{lightblue}{#1}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-5]

\begin{empheq}[box=\importantequation]{equation}
    \label{eq:michell}    
    \begin{aligned}        
        \nabla^2 \sigma_x + \frac{1}{1+\nu} \frac{\partial^2\Theta}{\partial x^2} &= -\frac{\nu}{1-\nu}\left(\frac{\partial X}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial Y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial Z}{\partial z}\right) - 2 \frac{\partial X}{\partial x} \\
        \nabla^2 \sigma_y + \frac{1}{1+\nu} \frac{\partial^2\Theta}{\partial y^2} &= -\frac{\nu}{1-\nu}\left(\frac{\partial X}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial Y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial Z}{\partial z}\right) - 2 \frac{\partial Y}{\partial y} \\
        \nabla^2 \sigma_z + \frac{1}{1+\nu} \frac{\partial^2\Theta}{\partial z^2} &= -\frac{\nu}{1-\nu}\left(\frac{\partial X}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial Y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial Z}{\partial z}\right) - 2 \frac{\partial Z}{\partial z}\\
        \nabla^2 \tau_{yz} + \frac{1}{1+\nu} \frac{\partial^2\Theta}{\partial y\partial z} &= -\left(\frac{\partial Y}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial Z}{\partial y}\right) \\
        \nabla^2 \tau_{xz} + \frac{1}{1+\nu} \frac{\partial^2\Theta}{\partial x\partial z} &= -\left(\frac{\partial X}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial Z}{\partial x}\right) \\
        \nabla^2 \tau_{xy} + \frac{1}{1+\nu} \frac{\partial^2\Theta}{\partial x\partial y} &= -\left(\frac{\partial X}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}\right)
    \end{aligned} 
\end{empheq}

\lipsum[1-4]    
    
\end{document}
```

And an image of my problem:

[image]

Comment: `empheq` is not breakable. Here it internally uses `aligned` which is not breakable. Besides where should the equation number go? It is probably better to rewrite the text such that the page before is filled or enough text is removed for it to go to the page before.